# Adding characters to string issue

Tags: php, string

I am adding characters to a string of words and not quite getting the result I need.

I have a string like this: `$string = "word word word word"`

The output I need is: `'word'+'word'+'word'+'word'`

What I am getting is: word+word+word+word+

Here is the function I am using:

```
$str = "word word word word";  
$str = implode("+", explode(" ", $str))."+";
echo $str;
```

Comment: what do you think this bit at the end is doing `."+";` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate single qoutes on both sides:

```
$str = "'".implode("'+'", explode(" ", $str))."'";
       ^^           ^ ^                        ^
// outside quotes   inside quotes           outside qoutes
```

Or like this:

```
$str = "'".str_replace(' ', "'+'", $str)."'";
```

Comment: My test works great, but when I include it as part of my form's post function prior to Inserting into the database the whole form post will not insert into mysql database.

Comment: @Jason i was wondering whats the context of this, how are you using it. you should have posted it earlier

Comment: probably the quotes not being escaped properly in the querry

Comment: @Ghost please see context above.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jason use `mysql_real_escape_string()` in the end before using it in the query

Answer (score 3):

Implode and concatenate the surrounding apostrophes like this:

```
$str = "word word word word";  
$str = "'" . implode("'+'", explode(" ", $str)) . "'";
echo $str;
```